# Does spring container generate any event, whenever it get request for get an instance of bean?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to identify how many bean requests served by the spring container and which class generates which request. So is there any event, which spring container generates whenever it receives a request to get an instance of bean. Request might be through @Autowired or container.getBean() method.

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your problem, mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationListenerAdapter implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO.
    }
}
```

Or you can handle a specific bean, using generics

```
@Component
public class ApplicationListenerAdapter implements ApplicationListener<YourCustomBean> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(YourCustomBean event) {
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works with `context.getBean`.